# Where in VSTS build logs I can see build parameters used?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have builds in VSTS. Where can I see build parameters used by that build ? I couldn't find anything like that in build output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to see them by default.
The parameters are however added to the environment variables.

Using Powershell to list these, you can at least get a peek at what it being passed.

```
Get-ChildItem env:
```

Full explanation here: [VSTS: Pass build variables into Powershell script task](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36997772/)